# UUIDField from django-extensions is not available in Class Based Views

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-extensions

I have a web application where I use a couple of UUIDFields.  In the Admin UI, in function based views and other Python code, these fields work as expected. However, when trying to list them in the 'fields' in a CBV, I get the error:

```
FieldError(message) django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (ct_id)
```

The subject field here is **ct_id**. But another one does the same.

From models.py:

```
ct_id = UUIDField(_("UUID"), version=4, help_text=_('A unique identifier for this PCT.'))
```

As mentioned above, they work in Admin lists:

```
    list_display = ('data_name','prj_name','published','ct_id')
admin.site.register(DvBoolean, DvBooleanAdmin)
```

In function based views to create JSON for DynaTree:

```
pct_json['tooltip'] = 'ct-'+pct.ct_id + " : " +pct.description
```

But in a CBV, this raises the error:

```
fields =['published','prj_name','data_name','ct_id',]
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?  I only want to render them for display, not for editing.

Thanks

Comment: may be you forgot to put `ct_id` in string as `'ct_id'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the only or best way to solve the problem.  But, since I needed to use get_context_data() in the view anyway.  I am now doing this to get ct_id into the view template:

```
def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
    context = super(DvStringUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    semlinks = []
    obj = get_object_or_404(DvString,pk=context['object'].id)
    if obj.resource_uri:
        urilist = obj.resource_uri.splitlines()
        attrlist = obj.sem_attr.splitlines()        
        for n in range(0,len(urilist)):
            semlinks.append(attrlist[n] + ' = ' + unquote(urilist[n]))

    context['semlinks'] = semlinks
    context['ct_id'] = obj.ct_id
    return context
```

IS there a bug in the way the UUIDField is defined causing it to not be available in CBVs?  This is at least a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a dumb question, but have you tried putting `ct_id` in quotes?

```
fields = [
    'published',
    'prj_name',
    'data_name', 
    'ct_id',
]
```

Comment: In the actual code it correctly has the quotes. In fact I just double checked to be sure, then fixed the question.  :-)